# Import PKCS11 public key in BouncyCastle

Tags: pkcs#11

I'm using a HSM to generate a pair of public/private elliptic key using PKCS11 commands, but I need to use the public key in BouncyCastle.

I can read the attribute EC_POINT in DER format, but I can not figure out how to import it in BouncyCastle.

This is my EC_POINT attribute:
CKA_EC_POINT:  04-39-04-ED-48-AE-D9-F8-02-CA-80-E1-1C-F2-3D-C9-C4-7D-B4-C5-9E-D2-53-A6-FE-27-D7-12-EF-C3-7F-2D-FC-D2-D0-31-62-8F-AF-60-19-E4-33-0F-63-A7-E4-95-33-0C-0D-D5-94-6C-92-B9-44-D8-2B

This is my working solution (thanks to Dave)

```
public ECPublicKeyParameters GetPubKeyFromParms(string curve, string pub) {
    var pc = ToByteArray(pub);
    var x9ecpar = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName(curve);
    var ecdp = new ECDomainParameters(x9ecpar.Curve, x9ecpar.G, x9ecpar.N);
    var basePoint = lsEccUtilities.ValidateECPublicKey(TlsEccUtilities.DeserializeECPublicKey(null, ecdp, pc));
    var subinfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(basePoint);
    var publicKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(subinfo);
    return publicKey;
}
```

The conversion of the signature from PKCS11 format to BouncyCastle format:

```
var r = signature.Take(signature.Length / 2).ToArray();
var s = signature.Skip(signature.Length / 2).ToArray();
var dersignature = new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence(
                    new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, r)),
                    new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(1, s))
                ).GetDerEncoded();
```

Comment: I've never heard of any DER format for an EC point; can you show an example in hex or other readable form? (Add to your Q with the edit button, not in comment(s), because discussion in comments can be deleted per StackExchange policy.)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I edited my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that indeed seems to be a (DER) OCTET STRING (tag 04, length 39 hex) containing a point in standard (X9.62/SEC1 et seq) uncompressed format (first octet 04) for a 28-octet (224-bit) curve. This seems silly to me, since all standard ASN.1 structures I know put a (point or other) pubkey in BIT STRING and include metadata, but apparently this is known or at least heard of because `asn1.x9.X9ECPoint` has a constructor for it. (For brevity and formatting, I omit the outer package `org.bouncycastle` that applies to everything.)

To use a point, you need to specify what curve it is on; I know of two 224-bit curves (more exactly, parameter sets) standardized by SECG and X9, secp224{k1,r1}, the latter of which (only) is adopted by NIST in FIPS 186-2+ as P-224, and two standardized by TeleTrusT as brainpool224{r1,t1}. Those are available built-in from `asn1.x9.ECNamedCurveTable` or `jce.ECNamedCurveTable` . There may be any number of nonstandard curves, which AFAICT you would have to create on your own. If you don't know what curve your uncompressed point is on, you can guess with effectively perfect accuracy by testing whether it satisfies the equations of candidate curves; I'm too lazy to do this for you. (A compressed point would be much harder to guess, perhaps impossible.)

Given the curve (from parameter set or direct) convert the DER to `ASN1OctetString` with `ASN1OctetString.getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(byte[]))` or just `ASN1OctetString.getInstance(Object/*byte[]*/)` which does the former for you, and then you can [directly construct an X9ECPoint](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x9/X9ECPoint.html#X9ECPoint-org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve-org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString-) and depending on what APIs you want to use it with, either call `.getPoint` to convert to a `math.ec.ECPoint` or construct related (more complicated) structures like `crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters`.

---

Added in response to comment since this is rather long, plus somewhat alters my answer:

I didn't realize you are using dotNET; my experience is with the Java version of Bouncy, and I'm impressed the two versions track closely enough your code even compiles. FWIW the Java equivalents of your revised code, with the one addition of explicitly building a `BCECPublicKey` from the parameters because JCE `Signature` takes only a `Key` type not a `Parameters` type, does work for me with a test keypair and data. You might try a similar exercise -- create a keypair and signature (for known data) in software and confirm if your code works for that case, then try to isolate the differences in the hardware-signed case. Although PKCS11 and other hardware devices are often designed to prevent device-generated keys from being exported to software, where they are presumably at greater risk of compromise, they are not always so strict on import -- you might be able to use your software-generated key in the hardware for comparison.

In addition to the generic reasons for any signature to not verify (wrong data, wrong hash -- which you apparently default, wrong key) another possibility *might* be the signature format. There are two commonly used formats (or encodings) for ECDSA (and DSA) signatures: either an ASN.1 SEQUENCE of INTEGERs in DER, or just the two integers in fixed binary format concatenated without any metadata. 'Standard' Java (more exactly, Java with the Sun/Oracle providers) uses only the ASN.1 format; Java with Bouncy defaults to ASN.1 but supports the fixed format for ECDSA if you change the algorithm name to `[hash]WITH{PLAIN,CVC}-ECDSA`, so I would expect Bouncy in dotNET (assuming your code is using it, though not explicitly stated) may do the same. I understand (but don't have personal experience) PKCS11 uses fixed format. If I feed Java Bouncy the wrong format it throws an exception rather than returning verify=false, but I don't know if dotNET could be different here. Look at your signature value in detail to check which format it is.

Comment: I edited again my question with your suggestion, but the data are never verified, is this code ok?

Comment: Sorry for delay; this scrolled out of view on my 'mailbox'. Rather too long for comments, so see edit.